# List of graphs in latex and numbering like Graph 1: , Graph 2:, ect

Tags: table-of-contents, graphs

I am using the trivfloat package to define new environment for graphs. So far so good. I would like to make a list of graphs in the following layout:

Graph 1: This is my graph

Graph 2: This is my second graph

With tables and figures I reconfigure the list with the following code:

```
\renewcommand{\cfttabaftersnum}{:}
\newlength\tablelen
\settowidth\tablelen{Table}
\addtolength\cfttabnumwidth{\tablelen}
\renewcommand\cfttabpresnum{Table }
```

How can I do this with the graph custom float env?

Comment: `\cfttabaftersnum` is not defined by the LaTeX kernel. Could you edit the question to be a full [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: nevermind:
i solved it with this command using before \listofgraphs

\makeatletter \renewcommand\numberline[1]{Graf #1:\hspace{1.8em}} \makeatother
\listofgraphs

Answer (score 2):

Converting alyo's comment into an answer:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\numberline[1]{Graf #1:\hspace{1.8em}}
\makeatother
\listofgraphs
```

(Of course, a full example would be a better answer!)