# Numbering and captioning pgfplots/tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, captions, tocloft

### Problem Description

I have a specific way I would like to caption my graphs created with `\begin{tikzpicture}`. More specifically I want to give them a numbering system, like that of figures and tables, but have the number and caption placed above the graph where the `Title` usually goes.

Additionally, I then want these graphs to have the Title of "Graph 2.9: ....." and then to be placed into a `\listofgraphs` section at the beginning of my document.

### MWE:

```
\documentclass [a4paper,10pt,draft]{report}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.6}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left, trim axis right]
            \begin{axis}[
                title={Pull-out glue strength for blocks with glued in cables},
                axis lines=box,
                xlabel={Block Number},
                ylabel={Failure Load (N)},
                xmin=1, xmax=5,
                ymin=0, ymax=9000,
                xtick={},
                ytick={},
                legend pos=outer north east,
                ymajorgrids=true,
                xmajorgrids=true,
                grid style=dashed,
                enlargelimits=true,
                ]
                
                \addplot[red,mark=square,mark size=2.9pt]coordinates{(1,6507) (2,6009) (3,5936) (4,5843) (5,6234)
                };\label{Blocks A}
                \addplot[blue,mark=square,mark size=2.9pt]coordinates{(1,1966) (2,1577) (3,2052) (4,1869) (5,2122)
                };\label{Blocks B}
                \addplot[green,mark=square,mark size=2.9pt]coordinates{(1,8435) (2,8027) (3,7648) (4,7865) (5,8123)
                };\label{Blocks C}
                \addplot[magenta,mark=square,mark size=2.9pt]coordinates{(1,3266) (2,2894) (3,3024) (4,2976) (5,3234)
                };\label{Blocks D}
                \addplot[orange,mark=square,mark size=2.9pt]coordinates{(1,6324) (2,6879) (3,5796) (4,6432) (5,6183)
                };\label{Blocks D}
                \addplot[violet,mark=square,mark size=2.9pt]coordinates{(1,2509) (2,2136) (3,2768) (4,2346) (5,2465)
                };\label{Blocks E}
                
                \legend{Blocks A, Blocks B, Blocks C, Blocks D, Blocks E, Blocks F}
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{}
        \label{graph: pull out results}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This produces the following:

[image]

### Desired Output/Solution

Whereas: I would want something that looks something like this:

[image]

And then for this to be placed in a `\listofgraphs` with the corresponding number and title.

Note: I already have figures and tables in my document, both in their own `\listof...`

I am using TexStudio and MikTex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try defining a new floating environment like in this post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95634/120578

```
\documentclass [a4paper,10pt]{report}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.6}

%koleygr: Added these from here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95634/120578
\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[placement={!ht},name=Graph]{Graph}

\captionsetup[Graph]{labelfont=bf}
\counterwithin{Graph}{chapter}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}




\begin{document}
    \section{}
    \begin{Graph}[!ht]
        \centering
        \caption{Pull-out glue strength for blocks with glued in cables}
        \label{graph: pull out results}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left, trim axis right]
            \begin{axis}[
                %title={Pull-out glue strength for blocks with glued in cables},
                axis lines=box,
                xlabel={Block Number},
                ylabel={Failure Load (N)},
                xmin=1, xmax=5,
                ymin=0, ymax=9000,
                xtick={},
                ytick={},
                legend pos=outer north east,
                ymajorgrids=true,
                xmajorgrids=true,
                grid style=dashed,
                enlargelimits=true,
                ]
                
                \addplot[red,mark=square,mark size=2.9pt]coordinates{(1,6507) (2,6009) (3,5936) (4,5843) (5,6234)
                };\label{Blocks A}
                \addplot[blue,mark=square,mark size=2.9pt]coordinates{(1,1966) (2,1577) (3,2052) (4,1869) (5,2122)
                };\label{Blocks B}
                \addplot[green,mark=square,mark size=2.9pt]coordinates{(1,8435) (2,8027) (3,7648) (4,7865) (5,8123)
                };\label{Blocks C}
                \addplot[magenta,mark=square,mark size=2.9pt]coordinates{(1,3266) (2,2894) (3,3024) (4,2976) (5,3234)
                };\label{Blocks D}
                \addplot[orange,mark=square,mark size=2.9pt]coordinates{(1,6324) (2,6879) (3,5796) (4,6432) (5,6183)
                };\label{Blocks E}
                \addplot[violet,mark=square,mark size=2.9pt]coordinates{(1,2509) (2,2136) (3,2768) (4,2346) (5,2465)
                };\label{Blocks F}
                
                \legend{Blocks A, Blocks B, Blocks C, Blocks D, Blocks E, Blocks F}
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{Graph}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Cool! So this works for the graph title, any idea how to combine this with the `\listofgraphs` code. I have tried a few examples from: [link](https://texblog.org/2008/07/13/define-your-own-list-of/) and from [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21009/list-of-graphs-in-latex-and-numbering-like-graph-1-graph-2-ect) but I can't seem to get them to work.

Comment: @AaronRhodes ... It already works... but we used capital `G` for `Graphs`... So, just try `\listofGraphs`

Comment: Actually, If I add `\listofGraph` to my code it prints out the correct thing. However TexStudio says it is an "unrecognized" command - But still prints the List correctly. Should I be bothered about fixing this?

Comment: just rename every `Graph` except of the `name=Graph` to `graph` ... I don't use TeXStudio ... But this will possibly help to get rid of this (and of TeXStudio later :P )

Comment: How you would go about having 2 graphs next to each other using this method? I had it working prior to this, but now it puts each new graph on a new line (There is no spaces between my `\end{Graph} and `\begin{Graph}`). I am assuming it does this as it would with any figure...which leads me to think a `\subfigure` solution would suffice, but unfortunately I can't get that to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Try using `\captionof{Graph}{Bla Bla}` inside `minipage`s next to each other

Comment: Would you be able to make another answer with a `MWE` of this? I am a little lost.

Comment: @AaronRhodes ... Please open o follow up question for this... It will not be helpful to other users in case it will solve multiple requests. Thanks

Comment: Here is the follow up question for anyone interested [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/654336/begingraph-side-by-side)