# \Begin{Graph} side by side

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphics, graphs

### Problem Description

This is a continuation of a question I had here: [Numbering and captioning pgfplots/tikzpicture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/654202/numbering-and-captioning-pgfplots-tikzpicture/654204?noredirect=1#comment1630499_654204)

Where We solved how to name Graphs in a specific way and in-turn generate a `\listofgraphs` at the beginning of the document.

When I follow that code, I can't seem to get 2 of my graphs to appear side by side. I assumed using a `\subfigure` environment would work but from what I tried, I could not get it to work. Another suggestion from @koleygr was: Try using `\captionof{Graph}{Bla Bla}` inside `minipages` next to each other. But this is where I got lost.

### MWE

For simplicity I am just using the same graph twice:

```
\documentclass [a4paper,10pt,draft]{report}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.6}

\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[placement={!ht},name=Graph]{Graph}
\captionsetup[Graph]{}
\counterwithin{Graph}{chapter}


\begin{document}
    
    \listofGraph
    
\section{Two graphs should be side by side}
    
\begin{Graph}[!ht]
    \centering
    \caption{glued in cables 1}
    \label{graph: pull out results}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left, trim axis right]
        \begin{axis}[
            %title={Pull-out glue strength for blocks with glued in cables},
            axis lines=box,
            xlabel={Block Number},
            ylabel={Failure Load (N)},
            xmin=1, xmax=5,
            ymin=0, ymax=9000,
            xtick={},
            ytick={},
            ymajorgrids=true,
            xmajorgrids=true,
            grid style=dashed,
            enlargelimits=true,
            ]
            
            \addplot[red,mark=square,mark size=2.9pt]coordinates{(1,6507) (2,6009) (3,5936) (4,5843) (5,6234)
            };\label{Blocks A}
            \addplot[blue,mark=square,mark size=2.9pt]coordinates{(1,1966) (2,1577) (3,2052) (4,1869) (5,2122)
            };\label{Blocks B}
            \addplot[green,mark=square,mark size=2.9pt]coordinates{(1,8435) (2,8027) (3,7648) (4,7865) (5,8123)
            };\label{Blocks C}
            \addplot[magenta,mark=square,mark size=2.9pt]coordinates{(1,3266) (2,2894) (3,3024) (4,2976) (5,3234)
            };\label{Blocks D}
            \addplot[orange,mark=square,mark size=2.9pt]coordinates{(1,6324) (2,6879) (3,5796) (4,6432) (5,6183)
            };\label{Blocks E}
            \addplot[violet,mark=square,mark size=2.9pt]coordinates{(1,2509) (2,2136) (3,2768) (4,2346) (5,2465)
            };\label{Blocks F}
            
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{Graph}%
\hspace{3pt}
%
\begin{Graph}[!ht]
    \centering
    \caption{glued in cables 2}
    \label{graph: pull out results}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left, trim axis right]
        \begin{axis}[
            %title={Pull-out glue strength for blocks with glued in cables},
            axis lines=box,
            xlabel={Block Number},
            ylabel={Failure Load (N)},
            xmin=1, xmax=5,
            ymin=0, ymax=9000,
            xtick={},
            ytick={},
            legend pos=outer north east,
            ymajorgrids=true,
            xmajorgrids=true,
            grid style=dashed,
            enlargelimits=true,
            ]
            
            \addplot[red,mark=square,mark size=2.9pt]coordinates{(1,6507) (2,6009) (3,5936) (4,5843) (5,6234)
            };\label{Blocks A}
            \addplot[blue,mark=square,mark size=2.9pt]coordinates{(1,1966) (2,1577) (3,2052) (4,1869) (5,2122)
            };\label{Blocks B}
            \addplot[green,mark=square,mark size=2.9pt]coordinates{(1,8435) (2,8027) (3,7648) (4,7865) (5,8123)
            };\label{Blocks C}
            \addplot[magenta,mark=square,mark size=2.9pt]coordinates{(1,3266) (2,2894) (3,3024) (4,2976) (5,3234)
            };\label{Blocks D}
            \addplot[orange,mark=square,mark size=2.9pt]coordinates{(1,6324) (2,6879) (3,5796) (4,6432) (5,6183)
            };\label{Blocks E}
            \addplot[violet,mark=square,mark size=2.9pt]coordinates{(1,2509) (2,2136) (3,2768) (4,2346) (5,2465)
            };\label{Blocks F}

        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{Graph}
    
        
\end{document}
```

This produces the following result:

[image]

### Desired Output/Solution

Whereas I would like something like this:

[image]

Comment: Have a look at the [`subcaption`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) package.

Comment: Also have look at [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5769/47927) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37581/47927) question.

Comment: I can kind of get [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5769/two-figures-side-by-side) to work but the graphs end up creating overfull boxes and spread into the right-hand margin. Changing `\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}` does not solve that issue entirely.

Comment: I just needed to add a scale to the `\begin{tikzpicture}`. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I think the `subcaption` package might not exactly be what you're after because then, both `subGraphs` would semantically belong to the same `Graph`. I still placed an answer that shows how to use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use two minipages inside a single `Graph` environment.

```
\documentclass [a4paper,10pt,draft]{report}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.6}

\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage{caption}

\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[placement={!ht},name=Graph]{Graph}
\captionsetup[Graph]{}
\counterwithin{Graph}{chapter}

\begin{document}
    
\listofGraph
    
\section{Two graphs should be side by side}
    
\begin{Graph}[!htp]

\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering

  \caption{glued in cables 1}
  \label{graph: pull out results 1}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left, trim axis right,scale=0.6]
    \begin{axis}[
      %title={Pull-out glue strength for blocks with glued in cables},
      axis lines=box,
      xlabel={Block Number},
      ylabel={Failure Load (N)},
      xmin=1, xmax=5,
      ymin=0, ymax=9000,
      xtick={},
      ytick={},
      ymajorgrids=true,
      xmajorgrids=true,
      grid style=dashed,
      enlargelimits=true,
   ]
   \addplot[red,mark=square,mark size=2.9pt] coordinates {
     (1,6507) (2,6009) (3,5936) (4,5843) (5,6234)
   };
   \addplot[blue,mark=square,mark size=2.9pt] coordinates {
     (1,1966) (2,1577) (3,2052) (4,1869) (5,2122)
   };
   \addplot[green,mark=square,mark size=2.9pt] coordinates {
     (1,8435) (2,8027) (3,7648) (4,7865) (5,8123)
   };
   \addplot[magenta,mark=square,mark size=2.9pt] coordinates {
     (1,3266) (2,2894) (3,3024) (4,2976) (5,3234)
   };
   \addplot[orange,mark=square,mark size=2.9pt] coordinates {
     (1,6324) (2,6879) (3,5796) (4,6432) (5,6183)
   };
   \addplot[violet,mark=square,mark size=2.9pt] coordinates {
     (1,2509) (2,2136) (3,2768) (4,2346) (5,2465)
   };
   \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
  \caption{glued in cables 2}
  \label{graph: pull out results 2}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left, trim axis right,scale=0.6]
    \begin{axis}[
      %title={Pull-out glue strength for blocks with glued in cables},
      axis lines=box,
      xlabel={Block Number},
      ylabel={Failure Load (N)},
      xmin=1, xmax=5,
      ymin=0, ymax=9000,
      xtick={},
      ytick={},
      legend pos=outer north east,
      ymajorgrids=true,
      xmajorgrids=true,
      grid style=dashed,
      enlargelimits=true,
    ]
    \addplot[red,mark=square,mark size=2.9pt] coordinates {
      (1,6507) (2,6009) (3,5936) (4,5843) (5,6234)
    };
    \addplot[blue,mark=square,mark size=2.9pt] coordinates {
      (1,1966) (2,1577) (3,2052) (4,1869) (5,2122)
    };
    \addplot[green,mark=square,mark size=2.9pt] coordinates {
      (1,8435) (2,8027) (3,7648) (4,7865) (5,8123)
    };
    \addplot[magenta,mark=square,mark size=2.9pt] coordinates {
      (1,3266) (2,2894) (3,3024) (4,2976) (5,3234)
    };
    \addplot[orange,mark=square,mark size=2.9pt] coordinates {
      (1,6324) (2,6879) (3,5796) (4,6432) (5,6183)
    };
    \addplot[violet,mark=square,mark size=2.9pt] coordinates {
      (1,2509) (2,2136) (3,2768) (4,2346) (5,2465)
    };
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}

\end{Graph}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `subcaption` package which creates a `subGraph` environment for your custom `Graph` environment automatically. You probably need to take care of the size of the plots and of the labels, of course.

You can adjust the way the numbering is done using several commands of which I put some in the code below. You should refer to the manual of the `subcaption` package for detailed information.

On a second thought and after reading the older question you link however, this is probably not exactly what you're after, because both `subGraph`s would then belong to the same `Graph` and hence share the same label. I still leave it here for reference.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,draft]{report}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.6}

\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[placement={!ht}, name=Graph]{Graph}
\captionsetup[Graph]{}

\DeclareCaptionSubType*{Graph}
\renewcommand\thesubGraph{Graph \theGraph (\alph{subGraph})}
\captionsetup[subGraph]{labelformat=simple, labelsep=colon}

\begin{document}
    
\listofGraph
    
\section{Two graphs should be side by side}
    
\begin{Graph}[!ht]
    \centering
    \begin{subGraph}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \caption{glued in cables 1}
        \label{graph: pull out results}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left, trim axis right, scale=0.6]
            \begin{axis}[
                %title={Pull-out glue strength for blocks with glued in cables},
                axis lines=box,
                xlabel={Block Number},
                ylabel={Failure Load (N)},
                xmin=1, xmax=5,
                ymin=0, ymax=9000,
                xtick={},
                ytick={},
                ymajorgrids=true,
                xmajorgrids=true,
                grid style=dashed,
                enlargelimits=true,
                ]
                
                \addplot[red,mark=square,mark size=2.9pt]coordinates{(1,6507) (2,6009) (3,5936) (4,5843) (5,6234)
                };\label{Blocks A}
                \addplot[blue,mark=square,mark size=2.9pt]coordinates{(1,1966) (2,1577) (3,2052) (4,1869) (5,2122)
                };\label{Blocks B}
                \addplot[green,mark=square,mark size=2.9pt]coordinates{(1,8435) (2,8027) (3,7648) (4,7865) (5,8123)
                };\label{Blocks C}
                \addplot[magenta,mark=square,mark size=2.9pt]coordinates{(1,3266) (2,2894) (3,3024) (4,2976) (5,3234)
                };\label{Blocks D}
                \addplot[orange,mark=square,mark size=2.9pt]coordinates{(1,6324) (2,6879) (3,5796) (4,6432) (5,6183)
                };\label{Blocks E}
                \addplot[violet,mark=square,mark size=2.9pt]coordinates{(1,2509) (2,2136) (3,2768) (4,2346) (5,2465)
                };\label{Blocks F}
                
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{subGraph}
    \begin{subGraph}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \caption{glued in cables 2}
        \label{graph: pull out results 2}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left, trim axis right, scale=0.6]
            \begin{axis}[
                %title={Pull-out glue strength for blocks with glued in cables},
                axis lines=box,
                xlabel={Block Number},
                ylabel={Failure Load (N)},
                xmin=1, xmax=5,
                ymin=0, ymax=9000,
                xtick={},
                ytick={},
                legend pos=outer north east,
                ymajorgrids=true,
                xmajorgrids=true,
                grid style=dashed,
                enlargelimits=true,
                ]
                
                \addplot[red,mark=square,mark size=2.9pt]coordinates{(1,6507) (2,6009) (3,5936) (4,5843) (5,6234)
                };\label{Blocks A 2}
                \addplot[blue,mark=square,mark size=2.9pt]coordinates{(1,1966) (2,1577) (3,2052) (4,1869) (5,2122)
                };\label{Blocks B 2}
                \addplot[green,mark=square,mark size=2.9pt]coordinates{(1,8435) (2,8027) (3,7648) (4,7865) (5,8123)
                };\label{Blocks C 2}
                \addplot[magenta,mark=square,mark size=2.9pt]coordinates{(1,3266) (2,2894) (3,3024) (4,2976) (5,3234)
                };\label{Blocks D 2}
                \addplot[orange,mark=square,mark size=2.9pt]coordinates{(1,6324) (2,6879) (3,5796) (4,6432) (5,6183)
                };\label{Blocks E 2}
                \addplot[violet,mark=square,mark size=2.9pt]coordinates{(1,2509) (2,2136) (3,2768) (4,2346) (5,2465)
                };\label{Blocks F 2}
                
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{subGraph}
\end{Graph}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]